# Purpose of wake_up_sync/wake_up_interruptible_sync in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm following an example in the [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-6#chp-6-sect-6.3) book:

```
if (temp =  = 0)
    wake_up_interruptible_sync(&scull_w_wait); /* awake other uid's */
return 0;
```

The author states:

> Here is an example of where calling wake_up_interruptible_sync makes sense. When we do
>   the wakeup, we are just about to return to user space, which is a natural scheduling
>   point for the system. Rather than potentially reschedule when we do the wakeup, it is
>   better to just call the "sync" version and finish our job.

I don't understand why using `wake_up_interruptible_sync` is better in this situation. The author implies that this call will prevent a reschedule -- which it does prevent within the call -- but after `wake_up_interruptible_sync` returns, couldn't another thread just take control of the CPU anyway before the `return 0` line?

So what is the difference between calling `wake_up_interruptible_sync` over the typical `wake_up_interruptible` if a thread can take control of the CPU regardless after each call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for using `_sync` is that we *know* that the scheduler will run within a short time, so we do not need to run it a second time.
However, this is just an optimization; if the scheduler *did* run again, nothing bad would happen.

A timer interrupt can indeed happen at any time, but it would be needed only if the scheduler did not already run recently for some other reason.

Comment: So `reschedule` is called within the `wake_up` function, and it is also called after a function return?

Comment: Not after any function return, when returning to user space.

Comment: I see, so we don't want to call `reschedule` in the `wake_up` function since it'll be called anyway on the return to userspace. By delaying it in `wake_up_sync` we get the chance of finishing the thread before going to sleep, and thus freeing the resources held by that thread; even though the thread could still end up sleeping, we increase the chance that it won't by delaying the `reschedule` call. Do I the reasoning correct now?

Comment: (SO doesn't allow comments as short as "yes".)